# Hyperref not expanding macros in section titles?

Tags: hyperref, pdftex, pdf

I defined a macro that typesets a technical name using math symbols, in my example `$\alpha$-thingy`.
When used in a `\section`, `\hyperref` would complain that it cannot use the symbol to compose the string in the pdf's index. So I defined the macro so it uses `\texorpdfstring` to provide the alternate text-only form `alpha-thingy` for the index.
This works very well unless the macro has an optional argument.
This MWE shows the issue:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\working}{\texorpdfstring{$\alpha$-thingy}{alpha-thingy}}
\newcommand{\nonworking}[1][thing]{\texorpdfstring{$\alpha$-#1}{alpha-#1}}

\begin{document}
  \section{Example \working}
  Hello \working.
  \section{Example \nonworking}
  Hello \nonworking.
  \section{Example \nonworking[thingy]}
  Hello \nonworking[thingy].
\end{document}
```

In the log I get two warnings:

```
W: mwe.tex:11 Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `\nonworking'
W: mwe.tex:13 Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `\nonworking'
```

How can I make `hyperref` happy without having to use `\texorpdfstring` directly in the `\section`'s argument each time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use optional arguments for bookmarks, because LaTeX's implementation uses `\futurelet`, which is not expandable. Bookmarks strings are not typeset by TeX, only converted to a string.

Since the macro with the optional argument does not have a following mandatory argument, there is no way detecting the optional argument using a macro-based approach.

The follwing example defines `\test` with an optional and a mandatory argument. The mandatory argument is not used, thus this is more an artificial example to show the way:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{numbered, open}

\newcommand{\working}{\texorpdfstring{$\alpha$-thingy}{\textalpha-thingy}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\test}{}
\def\test#1#{%
  \ifx\\#1\\%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\testA{thing}}%
  {\expandafter\testA\expandafter{\stripbrackets#1}}%
}
\newcommand*{\testA}[2]{%
  \texorpdfstring{$\alpha$-#1}{\textalpha-#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\stripbrackets}{}
\long\def\stripbrackets[#1]{#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \section{Example \working}
  Hello \working.
  \section{Example \test{}}
  Hello \test{}.
  \section{Example \test[thingy]{}}
  Hello \test[thingy]{}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Bookmarks:

> [image: Bookmarks]

**Remarks:**

- Package `bookmark` improves the bookmark handling and adds some features.
- Option `pdfencoding=auto` uses Unicode for the bookmarks and PDFDocEncoding, if Unicode is not necessary for the bookmark string.
- The basic trick is `\def\test#1#`. This puts the optional argument including the square brackets inside `#1`, if it is given. If the mandatory argument is directly following `\test`, then `#1` is empty, which is tested by `\ifx\\#1\\`.

Comment: wow, so much black magic...could you explain where does the second `#` in `\def\test#1#` come from?

Comment: @Bordaigorl The second `#` is a special case. At the end of the parameter text, it matches/expects an opening curly brace.

Comment: just two more questions: 1) where can I read more about this use of `#`? 2) suppose I do not need to support the first use of `\nonworkin` in my MWE but I can assume I always specify the optional argument when using the macro as a `\section`'s argument. Is there a less obscure way to handle that?

Comment: Couldn't one redefine futurelet in this context since the very restrictions that are causing problems here would presumably make it easier to fake futurelet in some way no?  But the more I think about it the more I'm unsure.

Comment: @PeterGerdes `\futurelet` is a non-expandable primitive command (like `\let`, `\def`, `\edef`) that cannot be simulated by macros.

Comment: I know that…I was saying something else dumb. I was wondering if you could do something else clever like just grab it without peeking use the fact that this context has more strict rules to back out the same effect (i.e. 'fix' the fact that you grabbed something you shouldn't have by reproducing the effect on tex state that it would have had if not grabbed) . The more I think about it the more it seems I was probably being dumb but I didn't mean to suggest you could literally peek at the stream.