# TOC / Bookmark and hyperlink inside a chapter / section title

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, hyperref, chapters, bookmarks

This is a followup question on [hyperlink inside chapter / section title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434292/hyperlink-inside-chapter-section-title)
in respect to the display in the TOC and bookmarks section of the resulting pdf.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage[pdftex,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{documentation for link to Section 1}
\chapter{documentation for link to \mbox{\protect\hyperlink{sec1}{Section 1}}}
\chapter{documentation for link to \hyperref[sec1]{Section 1}}

\hypertarget{sec1}{}\section{Section 1 Reference}
\label{sec1}\index{ref1@{ref1}}

\hypertarget{sec2}{}\section{Section 2 Reference}
documentation for \hyperlink{sec1}{Section 1}

\end{document}
```

This results in the contents page:
 [image]

and a Bookmark section:

[image]

In the contents page we see for chapter 2 and 3 (`\protect` and `\hyperref` implementation) an extra vertical red bar before the "Section 1" text, this is a an extra hyperref when clicking on "documentation for link" we jump to the relevant chapter, but wen clicking on the "Section 1" part we jump to the subsection. I think that in the the TOC part it is not good that depending on where one clicks on the line a different jump is made.

Looking at the bookmarks section we see here for the chapters 2 and 3 the texts "sec1Section" and "[sec1]Section"  so with extra "sec1" and "[sec1]".

How can I get a "clean" TOC / Bookmarks part?

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/227086/35864

Comment: is there a reason you can't use the optional "short title" for these titles, e.g., `\chapter[documentation for link to Section 1]{<full title>}` ?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for the suggestion, very interesting possibility, I have to investigate but first test looks like to work for me as well.

Comment: the "short title" option is the canonical mechanism for specifying an entry for the table of contents and running head, and that should be the first thing tried for the `book` class.  but some document classes do things differently, and it's worth knowing that that's the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\texorpdfstring` is your friend to put the TeX stuff in its first argument and the stuff that belongs to the PDF bookmark to the second:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{documentation for link to Section 1}
\chapter{documentation for link to
  \texorpdfstring{\hyperref[sec1]{Section \ref*{sec1}}}{Section \ref{sec1}}}

\section{Section 1 Reference}
\label{sec1}

\section{Section 2 Reference}
documentation for \autoref{sec1}

\end{document}
```

The table of contents is an example, why links in chapter/section titles should be avoided. The nested link "Section 1" makes it unclear, if the target should go to the outer link, the chapter/section title or to the link target to the inner link.

**Workaround A:** Option `linktocpage` of package `hyperref` to make the page numbers instead of the chapter/section titles to links.

**Workaround B:**

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage[pagebackref=true]{hyperref}

\newif\ifInToc
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\notoclink}[1]{%
  \ifInToc
    \begin{NoHyper}#1\end{NoHyper}%
  \else
    #1%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\InToctrue
\tableofcontents
\InTocfalse

\chapter{documentation for link to Section 1}
\chapter{documentation for link to
  \texorpdfstring{%
    \notoclink{\hyperref[sec1]{Section \ref*{sec1}}}%
  }{Section \ref{sec1}}}

\section{Section 1 Reference}
\label{sec1}\index{ref1@{ref1}}

\section{Section 2 Reference}
documentation for \autoref{sec1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves the Bookmark part, but in the TOC I still have that extra link.

Comment: As I need fixed texts as labels, although the MWE maybe did suggest a little bit different (sorry), but still very valuable for future reference,  I think Workaround B is the way to go for me.